# Scanning and printing variable data type "double" in C

Tags: c, printf, double, scanf

I'm studying algorithms and would love to learn. My problem is this, I can't output a number "600851475143" using the integer data type in C. So I switched to doubles. However the output is "0.0000". Can someone kindly tell me what I'm doing wrong? I simply want to scan and print any number in the double data type then I'm going to focus on getting the highest prime factor :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
double number;
double div = 2;
double highest = 2;

printf("Please input a number: ");
scanf("%lf", &number);

printf("\n You entered: %lf", &number);

while(number!=0){
    if(fmod(number,div) != 0){div = div + 1;}
    else{
    number = number / div;
    printf("\n %lf", div);

    if(highest < div){highest = div;}
    if(number == 1){break;}
    }
}
printf("\n The highest number is %lf", highest);

return 0;}
```

What I did:

1. Searched for "scan double in c" in google, learned the "%lf" is the right way to go, but the program doesn't show anything.
2. I checked out various questions in Stackoverflow like:

[Why does scanf need lf for doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f)

[Reading in double values with scanf in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730188/reading-in-double-values-with-scanf-in-c)

[Difference between float and double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double)

[Read and Write within a file in C (double it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857048/read-and-write-within-a-file-in-c-double-it)

[Reading and writing double precision from/to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463661/reading-and-writing-double-precision-from-to-files)

[float vs. double precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098558/float-vs-double-precision)

[Reading in double values with scanf in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730188/reading-in-double-values-with-scanf-in-c)

3. Other sites I searched:

http://www.technoburst.net/2011/07/reading-double-in-c-using-scanf.html

Thank you for enlightening me with your knowledge.

Comment: Use the `long` datatype instead of `int`, not double, since it is floating point as long as you need only integer arithmetic. As a format specifier use `%ld`.

Comment: `printf("\n You entered: %lf", &number);` --> `printf("\n You entered: %f", number);`  Drop `l` and `&`.

Comment: Start by checking return value of scanf...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling with a compiler with warnings shows the issue:

```
dbl.c:13:31: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type
     'double *' [-Wformat]
printf("\n You entered: %lf", &number);
                       ~~~   ^~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Change that line to:

```
printf("\n You entered: %lf", number);
```

You're trying to print the number's address instead of the number.

Also, try adding a newline to the end:

```
printf("\n The highest number is %lf\n", highest);
```

Since, you're working with integral numbers, though, I'd advise you to just use a `long long`, assuming you have a C99 compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
long long number;
long long div = 2;
long long highest = 2;

printf("Please input a number: ");
scanf("%lld", &number);

printf("\n You entered: %lld", number);

while(number!=0){
    if(number % div != 0){div = div + 1;}
    else{
    number = number / div;
    printf("\n %lld", div);

    if(highest < div){highest = div;}
    if(number == 1){break;}
    }
}
printf("\n The highest number is %lld\n", highest);

return 0;}
```

You can also reformat your code a bit for readability:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    long long number, div, highest;
    div = highest = 2;

    printf("Please input a number: ");
    scanf("%lld", &number);

    printf("\n You entered: %lld", number);

    while(number != 0) {
        if (number % div != 0) div += 1;
        else {
            number /= div;
            printf("\n %lld", div);

            if (highest < div) highest = div;
            if (number == 1) break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n The highest number is %lld\n", highest);

    return 0;
}
```

I would also advise doing the newlines a little differently, which leaves you with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    long long number, div, highest;
    div = highest = 2;

    printf("Please input a number: ");
    scanf("%lld", &number);

    printf("\n You entered: %lld\n", number);

    while(number != 0) {
        if (number % div != 0) div += 1;
        else {
            number /= div;
            printf("%lld\n", div);

            if (highest < div) highest = div;
            if (number == 1) break;
        }
    }
    printf("The highest number is %lld\n", highest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `number % div` instead of `fmod(number,div)`?

Comment: @kagushajeiel No problem. Also, try doing the change that chux mentioned in a comment on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in function `printf("%lf",&number)` should be `printf("%lf",number)`

Comment: You mean removing the ampersand sign? "&". The output still shows "0.00000" after I removed it -> build -> run.

Comment: Try without &, and save project. I tried this code without ampersend and it is workin. Save your project